# MySQL search same column(field) from multiple tables of the same structure

Tags: php, mysql

I have an MySQL database with multiple tables that have the exact structure, I want to search on the same column from each table.

Something like

```
SELECT part_number FROM * WHERE part_number LIKE $term
```

`*` is not working for all tables.

How can i make it work ?

Comment: `FROM *` is absolutely wrong statement.

Comment: If you have multiple tables with the **same** structure - that's one awful design and that leads to questions like you have now - how can you search something that someone (or you) designed in such a way that it's impossible to search it without weird approaches.

Comment: N.B. - Agreed, I need to restructure the way I am saving data.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: @CodeTroubleMaker: Perhaps consider storing the data differently in order to avoid queries like `WHERE field LIKE '%foo%'`. `LIKE` with wildcards like that is very likely to result in a full table scan... and it performs case-insensitive comparisons, too. This makes for slow queries!

Comment: Sorry, should not have posted the code like that. I am actually using a variable, LIKE $term.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) I guess.

```
(SELECT part_number FROM t1 WHERE part_number LIKE'%term%')
UNION
(SELECT part_number FROM t2 WHERE part_number LIKE'%term%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from table1,table2,table3 --(all tables) 
where table1.part_number LIKE'%term%' 
and table2.part_number LIKE'%term%' 
and table3.part_number LIKE'%term%'
--(all tables conditions)
```

it should work